# How to set Zxing Barcode Scanner scans only type CODE_128

Tags: android, zxing

Hi I have a program what using **Zxing BarcodeScanner** app.
I want to my program only get result from format CODE_128 and not scan any other format.
please help to me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Code128Reader` directly. That's the simplest way to only look for Code 128.